# Haskell IORef usage in concurrent setting

Tags: haskell, lock-free, memory-model, ioref

I am having hard time to understand Haskell's memory model. I got stuck implementing a simple lock-free hash map and while trying to reproduce the error on a smaller example I realized I have no idea what is going on.
I am only targeting x86_64

```
data TicketLock = TicketLock {cur :: !(IORef Int), next :: !(IORef Int)}

testTicket = do
  l <- TicketLock <$> newIORef 0 <*> newIORef 0
  mapConcurrently_ (\x -> replicateM_ 500000 (lockunlock l)) [0 .. 3]
  print "finished"

lockunlock :: TicketLock -> IO ()
lockunlock (TicketLock {..}) = do
  myticket <- atomicModifyIORef' next (\a -> (a + 1, a))
  let wait = do
        x <- readIORef cur -- atomicModifyIORef' cur (\a -> (a, a)) works correctly
        unless (x == myticket) wait
  wait
  print "lock acquired" -- to observe it gets stuck  
  atomicModifyIORef' cur (\a -> (a + 1, ())) -- unlock
```

The test gets stuck after a couple of thousand iterations.

What is going wrong with this code? I kind of expect it to fail because I guess iorefs can be [reordered](http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/01/so-you-want-to-add-a-new-concurrency-primitive-to-ghc/) by compiler but i can't figure out what exactly is going on. Is it observable in generated STG code or cmm code?

My real question is why adding barriers does not fix the problem? I tried adding barriers (from `atomics-primops` package) after every line of the `lockunlock` function and problem still continues.

I also tried using `AtomicCounter` from `atomic-primops` package, the problem is the same, even though incrCounter is implemented by fetch-add instruction the test somehow gets stuck after couple of thousand iterations, even with barriers all over the code.

```
data BetterTicketLock = BetterTicketLock {curb :: !(AtomicCounter), nextb :: !(AtomicCounter)}

testTicketb = do
  l <- BetterTicketLock <$> newCounter 1 <*> newCounter 0
  mapConcurrently_ (\x -> replicateM_ 500000 (lockunlockb l)) [0 .. 3]
  print "finished"

lockunlockb :: BetterTicketLock -> IO ()
lockunlockb (BetterTicketLock {..}) = do
  myticket <- incrCounter 1 nextb -- it returns new value not old value
  let wait = do
        x <- incrCounter 0 curb -- I am not even using readCounter which is similar to readIOref
        unless (x == myticket) wait
  wait
  print "lock acquired" 
  void $ incrCounter 1 curb
```

Ideally i want a way to reason about haskell programs like in rust using acquire-release semantics how is the following can be converted to Haskell?

```
struct TicketLock { current: AtomicUsize,  next: AtomicUsize}
impl TicketLock  {
    fn new() -> Self{
            TicketLock {current: AtomicUsize::new(0),next: AtomicUsize::new(0)}   
    }
    fn lockunlock(&self) {
        let ticket = self.next.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed); 
        while self.current.load(Ordering::Acquire) != ticket { }
        // critical section
        let _ = self.current.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Release); 
    }
}
```

Edit: For some reason this works as expected without any performance penalty. Is it because of barriers being ignored in tight loops?

```
lockunlock (TicketLock {..}) s = do
  myticket <- atomicModifyIORef' next (\a -> (a + 1, a))
  let wait = do
        x <- readIORef cur
        unless (x == myticket) $ threadDelay 0 >> wait
  wait
  modifyIORef' s (+ 1)
  atomicModifyIORef' cur (\a -> (a + 1, ())) -- unlock
```

Comment: I never expect `readIORef` to have semantics stronger than “returns some value that was at one point in that `IORef`“ in a concurrent setting. In particular, I don't think there's any guarantee of any memory barrier other than `atomicModifyIORef` being respected. I don't have any references for this, so I hesitate to present it as an answer - but it does explain the failure case you see.

Comment: I'm not sure "Haskell" can really have a memory model, as such. There's too much going on at the level of memory that is completely unobservable at the language level. The memory model you're trying to understand would be specifically about IORefs, which may not have much to do with a memory model you could try to observe for the rest of Haskell (using unsafe features I guess?), I think?

Answer (score 4):

You're running into a pathological case with the implementation of pre-emptive multitasking in GHC. See [the documentation of the Control.Concurrent module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#g:13):

> GHC implements pre-emptive multitasking: the execution of threads are interleaved in a random fashion. More specifically, a thread may be pre-empted whenever it allocates some memory, which unfortunately means that tight loops which do no allocation tend to lock out other threads (this only seems to happen with pathological benchmark-style code, however).

Your `wait` loop seems to not allocate anything, so it cannot be pre-empted. You can solve this issue by inserting a manual [`yield`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:yield):

```hs
lockunlock :: TicketLock -> IO ()
lockunlock (TicketLock{..}) = do
  myticket <- atomicModifyIORef' next (\a -> (a + 1, a))
  let wait = do
        x <- readIORef cur
        unless (x == myticket) (yield *> wait)
  wait
  print "lock acquired"
  atomicModifyIORef' cur (\a -> (a + 1, ()))
```

Alternatively, you can compile with [`-fno-omit-yields`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--fomit-yields).

I haven't been able to figure anything more out by trying to debug using the eventlog, because even that seems to be blocked. As K.A. Buhr remarks below he has written [a better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59991233/15207568):

> Less obviously, the same thing can happen even if you compile with `-threaded` and use `+RTS -N` options. The problem is that an uncooperative thread can starve out the runtime scheduler itself. If at some point the uncooperative thread is the only thread currently scheduled to run, it will become uninterruptible, and the scheduler will never be re-run to consider scheduling additional threads, even if they could run on other O/S threads.

Comment: But nothing needs to yield. All 4 threads can run concurrently. sure it will run slow without any backoff but slowness is not the issue here it gets stuck. Barriers should ensure correct ordering of memory operations and all threads should finish eventually.

Comment: My guess would be that GHC's scheduler doesn't like OS threads being blocked indefinitely. But I will try to debug this further.

Comment: @boran If you have fewer OS threads than Haskell threads, then presumably  one bad interleaving would be: all Haskell threads acquire a ticket, then all the OS threads begin executing a Haskell thread other than the one that got the first ticket. Since they never yield, the one that got the first ticket never gets a chance to advance `cur`. (Perhaps you were unaware that GHC offers n-to-m Green threads?)

Comment: @Daniel Wagner Yeah i understood that. In my test setup getNumCapabilities returns 24 so all 4 threads can run concurrently. Am i missing something?

Comment: @boran Nope, not missing anything! In that case, I continue to be confused (as I was when I first read the question). Almost all of my 130k Internet points comes from answering questions here in the Haskell tag, so you might take that as some evidence that this is not just you being a noob, if that's any comfort.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59987940/haskell-computationally-intensive-thread-blocks-all-other-threads/59991233#59991233) seem relevant?  In particular, see the paragraph that starts, ironically enough, with "Obviously...".

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I guess the only remaining question is how can it happen that only one thread remains scheduled? Shouldn't it just spawn four threads in the beginning and keep using those? Why does it seem to do some work and then suddenly deadlock?

Comment: @Daniel Wagner i am really thinking that most of the time using haskell so thanks it means surprisingly a lot.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr yes the answer is perfect thanks a lot.